# Encrypt/Decrypt data in cookie and hide decryption algorithm in JS file

Tags: javascript, cookies

I apologize if this is a duplicate. I looked quite a bit and didn't find one that exactly answered this question.

I'm working on a Vanilla JS, Spring Boot application and am using Gmail Oauth to authenticate users. I need to send some login related data (like roles, username, email id) from the server to the browser. This data also needs to be shared across HTML pages.
After login, I'm redirecting the user to a HTML page and returning the above login data using a cookie. The JS code retrieves the data from the cookie.
I'm planning to encrypt the data in the cookie on the server side and decrypt it using JS on the client side. The issue is that the JS file can be viewed by the end user and the decryption algorithm will be visible to them. I don't want the JS file to be visible. I researched this and found a couple of articles. Listing one here
https://dev.to/dhairyashah/how-to-hide-javascript-code-in-view-source-39kg/comments

This is a REST API project and no session state is allowed on the server.
If I don't encrypt/decrypt, the end user can change the roles or the email id in the cookie. Changing the roles can cause undesirable behavior on the client side. Of course, I have spring security role based authorization set up on the server. So nothing untoward will happen on the server, but the UI behavior will be odd.

Here's my question. I don't see any point in encrypting/decrypting if I cannot successfully hide the JS file. Should I not do it since nothing bad can happen on the server side?

I have explained it above

Comment: There is no way to _hide_ anything that happens on the client side. Maybe you should look into JWT, https://jwt.io ?

Comment: _"So nothing untoward will happen on the server, but the UI behavior will be odd."_ - but only for the user, who manipulated stuff in the first place, right? Which is a case I usually can't be bothered about too much. As long as my system does not _expose_ any sensitive information, I don't care too much, _how_ it behaves in such a situation. I don't "owe" anyone who tries to manipulate parameters, outside of the boundaries in which they are supposed to, a _proper_ response / behavior.

Comment: CBroe - I appreciate the response and I agree with your explanation. Thanks a lot again.